# Select list elements close to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select an li item with class `menu-item menu-item-depth-1` that query all element with a class `menu-item menu-item-depth-2` that are close to the selected element. If I reach an other element with class `menu-item menu-item-depth-1` my query stops:

```
<li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-0"></li> 
<li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-0"></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-1"></li><! -- 1st depth-1 element -->
<li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2"></li><! -- close element to 1st depth-1 -->
<li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2"></li><! -- close element to 1st depth-1 -->
<li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2"></li><! -- close element to 1st depth-1 -->
<li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2"></li><! -- close element to 1st depth-1 -->
<li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-1"></li><! -- 2nd depth-1 element -->
<li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2"></li><! -- not close element to 1st depth-1 -->
<li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2"></li><! -- not close element to 1st depth-1 -->
<li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2"></li><! -- not close element to 1st depth-1 -->
<li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2"></li><! -- not close element to 1st depth-1 -->
```

For example, if I select 1st depth-1 element, I want to query just element width depth-2 that are close element to 1st depth-1.

Comment: @ Eddy : what problem are you facing?

Comment: I want to hide some fields in depth-2 based on another fields in depth-1 and i don't know how to query like explained in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to loop over all `li` elements directly after the clicked `li` element and check the class attribute on each iteration. When the class of an element matches the clicked element class then use `return` to exit the loop.

You can try the following:

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-0">0</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-0">0</li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-1">1</li>
    <! -- 1st depth-1 element -->
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2">2</li>
    <! -- close element to 1st depth-1 -->
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2">2</li>
    <! -- close element to 1st depth-1 -->
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2">2</li>
    <! -- close element to 1st depth-1 -->
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2">2</li>
    <! -- close element to 1st depth-1 -->
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-1">1</li>
    <! -- 2nd depth-1 element -->
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2">2</li>
    <! -- not close element to 1st depth-1 -->
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2">2</li>
    <! -- not close element to 1st depth-1 -->
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2">2</li>
    <! -- not close element to 1st depth-1 -->
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-depth-2">2</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$("ul li").click(function () {
    // reset background for example
    $(".menu-item").css("background", "#fff");

    $this = $(this);
    var clickedClass = $this.attr('class').split(' ').pop();
    var nextNumber = parseInt(clickedClass.replace("menu-item-depth-", "")) + 1;

    var nextElements = $this.nextAll();
    for (var i = 0; i < nextElements.length; i++) {
        var $element = $(nextElements[i]);
        if ($element.hasClass("menu-item-depth-" + nextNumber)) {
            $element.css("background-color", "green");
        } else if ($element.hasClass(clickedClass)) {
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle to showcase the above example, click on the li's to see the ones being selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/1kamsz05/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function getNextClose(selector, selector2)
{

    var matches = null, next = jQuery(selector).next();
    while (!next.is(selector) && next.is(selector2) )
    {
        if ( !matches ) matches = next;
        else matches = matches.add(next);
        next = next.next();
    }
    return matches;
}
```

use like this:

```
var matches = getNextClose('.menu-item.menu-item-depth-1:first', '.menu-item.menu-item-depth-2');
```

**Note** that if no matches are found `matches` will be `null` and **not** an empty `jQuery object`